# How to getimagesize() when fetch image data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, image

What is correct parameters for `getimagesize($image_temp)` and `imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp)` when image fetch from database.
 Please help me, thanks.

**TABLE IN DB**

```
CREATE TABLE `image` (
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `mime` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `size` int(20) NOT NULL,
 `data` mediumblob NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `userid` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**PHP**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `image` WHERE ids = '0' limit 1";
$sqlquery = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery);

    $image_name = $data['name']; //file name
    $image_size = $data['size']; //file size
    $image_temp = $data['data']; //file blob
    $image_type = $data['mime']; //file type

    // Parameter incorrect
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_temp);

    // Parameter incorrect
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp);
```

**ERROR**
Warning: : failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\php\imageread.php on line 18

Warning: : failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\php\imageread.php on line 31

Answer (score 1):

It seems your image is stored as a BLOB in your database, and your query retrieves the image data.

In this case you should use `getimagesizefromstring()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php) instead of `getimagesize()` to find out the image's dimensions.

But beware, the MySQL bindings sometimes have difficulty retrieving large BLOBs from the database.